# Regular expression for extracting an optional piece using a keyword

Tags: python, regex

I would like to be able to extract 2 pieces from a string, which are potentially separated by a specific keyword. If the keyword is not there then assume only the first piece is provided. To give more concrete (and clearer) example:

'a key b' ---> return (a,b)

'a' ( with no ' key ' string identified) ---> return (a,'')

I first tried using the regex "(.*) key (.*)" which obviously does not work for case 2... then "(.*)( key )?(.*)" but that does not work for case 1... I'm working with Python and findall() function.

Any idea pls? I feel it has to do with the greedy "(.*)" but cannot figure it out.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> "a key b".split(" key ")
['a', 'b']
>>> "a".split(" key ")
['a']
>>>
```

Comment: ah, didn't even think about that as i was already working with a regex around the shape of a... thanks!

Comment: It's true.  I can confirm Avinash Raj beat me by 5 seconds.  I gave you an upvote Avinash

Comment: would you know of a way to embed that within a regex string? as actually I am already extracting things from 'a'.

Comment: @fdb `re.split(r'\s+key\s+', s)`

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `string.split()`?

```
string.split(' key ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Split would seem a natural fit for your problem:

```
def extract(text):
    return ([part.strip() for part in text.split("key", 1)] + [''])[:2]

for test in ["a key b", "a", "a key", "a longer example of key is this"]:
    print extract(test)
```

This would give you the following results:

```
['a', 'b']
['a', '']
['a', '']
['a longer example of', 'is this']
```

If you really wish to use a regular expression, the following could be used to give the same results:

```
def extract(text):
    return re.search(r'(.*?)(?:\s+key|\Z)\s*(.*)', text).groups()
```